# Lotus Notes: A view of that name cannot be found in the specified database

Tags: view, field, lotus-notes

There is a computed hidden number field called `flag`, which has its default value:

```
 _view := "vwAll";

code := @Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ;"vwSetupCode" ; 1 )  ); 

x :=@Sort(@Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ;  code; _view; 1 ) );[Ascending]);

@If(txt_1=""|txt_2="";5;
@If(@IsNotMember(@UpperCase(txt_1);x);1;
@If(@IsNotMember(@UpperCase(txt_2);x);0;
2)))
```

The `_view` is from another DB which has its code in the `vwSetupCode`.

It works fine for some users, but for couple of them I get the error:

```
Field "flag': `A view of that name cannot be found in the specified database`.
```

There is a issue at the ACL? PLease help.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: What's the value of 'code' when you run it?

Comment: It is the another DB'code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the view is protected and not accessible to all users.

Open view in designer and check last tab of view properties. There you can find a list of "Who may use this view". Probably check-box "All readers or above" is not set and some of your users are not in groups listed there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The checkbox "All readers or above" is checked, I verified it.

Comment: Ok. Which ACL level have those users? At least "Reader"?

Comment: There's the "server name" in the ACL of the db which contains the view. So, it acts like a group? Containing all the users?

Comment: ACL has to contain a group with users as members or users itself. Just server or server group doesn't help.

Comment: I added one user in the ACL of the database which contains the view. It has effect immediately? Or the user must re-start the DB?

Comment: Should work right away. Let user access view in db direct in Notes client for test.

Comment: I did add the person, and same error. Btw, that DB has as Default - acces Editor. This issue gives me headache. So , the problem is 100% at the view  ( or, implicitly, at the DB ACL which contains the view )

Comment: Can users open this view in Notes client?

Comment: You mean to put it in an outline entry? The view is not used visually in that DB, is just for DBColumn's help

Comment: With "Shift + Ctrl" pressed click menu "View / Go To..." and select hidden view to open.

Comment: Please check also if users have access to view "vwSetupCode" in current db. Look at view properties too. If that is ok, show with `@Prompt([OK]; "code", code)` what "code" contains for those users.

Comment: What I did: I put myself to have just Editor access - as Default to the 2nd database. And I get no errors, it works for me. The Setup Code view is ok

Comment: If Default is Editor and view is not protected then all users have access to that view. The error is then with getting db server and name in variable "code". Look at my previous comments.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. The view SetupCode is contained by an outline entry. I created there an action button with:code := Unique ( DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; DbName ;"vwSetupCod" ; 1 )  ); Prompt([Ok];"Code:";code). Now, I will see what code contains for those users

Comment: So, a test with one user which is Default - Editor access in the 2nd DB. It gives him the error. The code is the same when he prompted it, the code is OK.

Comment: Does the value of code return something like "":"databaseName.nsf", where it ends up searching the user's local replica? That could easily vary between users.

Answer (score 1):

code := @Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ;"vwSetupCode" ; 1 )  );

Or if the returned value **code** is multi-valued.  IE the first @DBColumn returned unique multi-values ... good luck